# Why is the text of TextView not restored when setRetainInstance(true) has been called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I called setRetainInstance(true) for a fragment. I added an EditText and TextView on the fragment. When rotated, the text in the EditText survived, but the text in the TextView was gone.

I think I can manually restore the text of the TextView, but I wonder why the system automatically restores the text for EditText, and not for TextView. Did I do something wrong?

Steps to reproduce.

1. Type "android" in the EditText
2. Press the [Test 1] button. The TextView now displays "android"
3. Rotate the device.

Result

The EditText has "android", but the TextView is empty.

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyFragment";
    EditText etInput;
    Button btnTest1;
    TextView tvMessage;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView()");
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        etInput = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        btnTest1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnTest1);
        btnTest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                tvMessage.setText(etInput.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "btnTest1 was clicked");
            }
        });

        tvMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        return v;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment mf = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.placeholder);
        if(mf == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "creating new my fragment");
            mf = new MyFragment();
            mf.setRetainInstance(true);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, mf).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

my_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/etInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest1"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="Fragment Test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: setRetainInstanceState will retain the state of the Fragment itself, not the UI/view contained in that fragment. To do that you will need to save some values globally in the fragment and then reset the views to those values in onCreateView.

Comment: I read somewhere that if you define the fragment in xml explicitly (with <fragment> tag) this will work but I don't know if it helps you

Comment: Then, why was the text of EditText restored automatically?

Comment: @SinJeong-hun the document I read exactly had the same problem for couple of UI components

Comment: Did you mean replacing <FrameLayout> with <fragment>? I tried, but it caused an inflation exception.

Comment: when you replace with <fragment> you don't need to inflate anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to enable auto restoration of `TextView`, you need to set `freezesText` attribute to `true` in your xml (or call `setFreezesText(true)`).

For `TextView`, `freezesText` default value is `false`, but in case of `EditText`, default value is `true`.

From documentation of [`freezesText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:freezesText):

> If set, the text view will include its current complete text inside of
>   its frozen icicle in addition to meta-data such as the current cursor
>   position. By default this is disabled; it can be useful when the
>   contents of a text view is not stored in a persistent place such as a
>   content provider. For EditText it is always enabled, regardless of the
>   value of the attribute.

Comment: freezesText applies to Button also if you want to restore text on it, because Button is TextView.